# IMPORTXML: "Imported content is empty" when querying 1st Google search result

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I want to fetch the URL of the 1st Google search result to Google Sheets.

`=IMPORTXML(F2;"//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div/div[1]/a/@href")`

where F2 is `=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q="&E2&"&num=1")` (E2 is the search keyword)

Sheets keep returning "Imported content is empty."

Any ideas on how to solve this? Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use an alternative (like for example **https://www.ecosia.org/**) search engine because google disabled scraping of search results into google sheets